# How to Delete Largest Variable in a List

Tags: python, arrays, list, sorting

I am currently working on some code that prints the largest item from a list and then deletes that largest item. It repeats this, printing the items in descending order.

Each part of the list contains a volunteer name, the total amount of bags they have counted, and their accuracy. The algorithm checks for the part with the largest accuracy, and then prints all three aforementioned variables.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to find the position of the largest part of the list (its index), not allowing me to delete it.

I have already tried using the `list.index` command as well as just typing `del[maximum = max(VolunteerList, key = operator.itemgetter(2))]` and neither work.

```
Volunteer1TotalBags = 5
Volunteer2TotalBags = 23
Volunteer3TotalBags = 567
Volunteer4TotalBags = 12
Volunteer5TotalBags = 90
Volunteer6TotalBags = 11

Volunteer1Accuracy = 12
Volunteer2Accuracy = 65
Volunteer3Accuracy = 3
Volunteer4Accuracy = 5
Volunteer5Accuracy = 345
Volunteer6Accuracy = 43

def Option1():
    global Volunteer1Forename
    global Volunteer2Forename
    global Volunteer3Forename
    global Volunteer4Forename
    global Volunteer5Forename
    global Volunteer6Forename
    global Volunteer1Surname
    global Volunteer2Surname
    global Volunteer3Surname
    global Volunteer4Surname
    global Volunteer5Surname
    global Volunteer6Surname
    VolunteerData() # This calls back the variables above from a previous function
    Volunteer1FullName = Volunteer1Forename + Volunteer1Surname + "'s Total Bags and Accuracy"
    Volunteer2FullName = Volunteer2Forename + Volunteer2Surname + "'s Total Bags and Accuracy"
    Volunteer3FullName = Volunteer3Forename + Volunteer3Surname + "'s Total Bags and Accuracy"
    Volunteer4FullName = Volunteer4Forename + Volunteer4Surname + "'s Total Bags and Accuracy"
    Volunteer5FullName = Volunteer5Forename + Volunteer5Surname + "'s Total Bags and Accuracy"
    Volunteer6FullName = Volunteer6Forename + Volunteer6Surname + "'s Total Bags and Accuracy"
    VolunteerList = {(Volunteer1FullName, Volunteer1TotalBags, Volunteer1Accuracy), (Volunteer2FullName, Volunteer2TotalBags, Volunteer2Accuracy), (Volunteer3FullName, Volunteer3TotalBags, Volunteer3Accuracy), (Volunteer4FullName, Volunteer4TotalBags, Volunteer4Accuracy), (Volunteer5FullName, Volunteer5TotalBags, Volunteer5Accuracy), (Volunteer6FullName, Volunteer6TotalBags, Volunteer6Accuracy)}
    maximum = max(VolunteerList, key = operator.itemgetter(2))
    maximumindex = VolunteerList.index(max(VolunteerList, key = operator.itemgetter(2)))
    print(maximum)
    del[maximumindex]
Option1()
```

This is the error I get, and it's because the program can't generate an index for the maximum part of the list:

```
maximumindex = VolunteerList.index(max(VolunteerList, key = operator.itemgetter(2)))
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'index'
```

Please tell me if you don't understand my predicament, I don't know if I worded it clearly enough.

Comment: You can modify selection sort. Determine the index of maximum element using it, and then once, you have it, just do `del arr[index]`, or whatever you wish to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a `set` here.

```
VolunteerList = {(Volunteer1FullName, Volunteer1TotalBags, Volunteer1Accuracy), (Volunteer2FullName, Volunteer2TotalBags, Volunteer2Accuracy), (Volunteer3FullName, Volunteer3TotalBags, Volunteer3Accuracy), (Volunteer4FullName, Volunteer4TotalBags, Volunteer4Accuracy), (Volunteer5FullName, Volunteer5TotalBags, Volunteer5Accuracy), (Volunteer6FullName, Volunteer6TotalBags, Volunteer6Accuracy)}
```

`set`s don't support indexing. You probably want a `list`

```
VolunteerList = [(Volunteer1FullName, Volunteer1TotalBags, Volunteer1Accuracy), (Volunteer2FullName, Volunteer2TotalBags, Volunteer2Accuracy), (Volunteer3FullName, Volunteer3TotalBags, Volunteer3Accuracy), (Volunteer4FullName, Volunteer4TotalBags, Volunteer4Accuracy), (Volunteer5FullName, Volunteer5TotalBags, Volunteer5Accuracy), (Volunteer6FullName, Volunteer6TotalBags, Volunteer6Accuracy)]
```

Replaces `{` with `[`